# Wordpress Loop For Custom HTML/CSS

Tags: php, html, wordpress, loops, counter

I'm fairly new to PHP and I'm trying to do something that is probably easy, but I can't seem to get it working. I'm trying to set up a WordPress loop so that it loads one style for the first 3, then another style for the next 6, and so on.

So far I've tried playing around with counters, but with no luck. The idea is that the first three posts on the homepage will be with title and meta above large images and excerpts under the image. The next 6 will be with a square image off to the left and title and excerpt to the right. The only way I can think of to achieve this is to use two separate "content" pages.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php $count = 1; ?>
                <?php if ($count <=3) { ?>
                    <?php get_template_part( 'content', '' );
                    $count++; ?>
                <?php } if ($count > 3) { 
                    get_template_part( 'content', 'small' );
                } ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stay with your current approach, this should fix your issues.
Just declare and initialize `$count` **before** the loop, otherwise you always reset its value to `1`.

```
<?php $count = 0; ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php $count++; ?>
    <?php if ($count <=3) { ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'content', '' ); ?>
    <?php } if ($count > 3) { 
        get_template_part( 'content', 'small' );
    } ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```